# Why does this SQL join work in 1 order but not the other?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 SQL joins here, one returns good results, the other returns 0 result set. **Why is this?** They are very similar except for join/column/table order. (By the way I'm using MySQL here)

**Working Join (returns over 240,000 rows of good data)**

```
SELECT 
   t1.email AS "email", 
   t1.record_id AS "record_id", 
   t2.status AS "status",
   t3.item_record_id AS "item_record_id",
   t1.ordered_at AS "started_at"

FROM `rs_orders` t1 

INNER JOIN `cb_all_transactions` t2 
ON t1.record_id = CONCAT('cb_sl_', t2.receipt) 

INNER JOIN `rs_order_items` t3
ON t1.record_id = t3.order_record_id

WHERE t2.recurring = 'true' 

ORDER BY t1.ordered_at ASC
```

**NON Working Join (returns 0 rows)**

```
SELECT 
   t1.email AS "email", 
   t1.record_id AS "record_id",
   t1.ordered_at AS "started_at",
   t2.item_record_id AS "item_record_id",
   t3.status AS "status"

FROM rs_orders t1

INNER JOIN rs_order_items t2
ON t1.record_id = t2.order_record_id

INNER JOIN cb_all_transactions t3
ON t2.order_record_id = CONCAT('cb_sl_' + t3.receipt)

WHERE t3.recurring = 'true'
```

Comment: You did a good job of confusing yourself... stay consistent with the naming of t2/t3 with the tables that you join and with the fields that you're using for the join and it might become clearer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're not the same. The second has `CONCAT('cb_sl_' + t3.receipt)`. Replace `+` with `,`.